Omit unnecessary variables in controller method signature in Laravel
I often use multi-domain applications (e.g. multi-tenant) that require the domain to be part of a URL when using route(). Thus, the domain is needed as a route parameter, which is defined like this in routes/web.php:
Route::group([
    'domain' => '{domain}',
], function () {
    Route::get('{someModel}', [\App\Http\Controllers\SomeModelController::class, 'show']);
// ... some other routes
});

RouteServiceProvider.php
Route::model('someModel', SomeModel::class);

SomeModelController.php
This works but needs the $domain variable in the signature that is not needed in the code below:
public function show(string $domain, SomeModel $someModel): JsonResponse
{
    return response()->json($someModel);
}

This is what I want to be using, but causes an error:

"Argument #1 ($someModel) must be of type App\Models\SomeModel, string given"

public function show(SomeModel $someModel): JsonResponse
{
    return response()->json($someModel);
}

As shown, some controller methods do not need the $domain variable (while others do). However, the variable needs to be injected as the controller expects the variables in the same order as in the route definition chain. I do understand where the error is coming from but I think I'm missing something in setting up dependency injection (DI) as there is no need for $domain. DI should be able to see by the variable name "someModel" that domain is not needed here.
I do not want to remove domain from the route parameters for several reasons. I just want to omit it in the controller method signatures if not needed.
Does anyone know how?

You are stating you have an error, can you share it? I am missing something, it is no clear exactly what issues you are having

I stated the error above. See my comment in SomeModelController.php.


As shown, some controller methods do not need the $domain variable (while others do).

In that case you should define your route outside the Route group.
Route::group([
'domain' => '{domain}',
], function () {....

For more information see the official docs going to the link..
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing
For dependency injection(Model binding through route),see this...
https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#route-model-binding

I know, but as said, I need the parameter for URL generation via route() in any case. So this is not a viable solution.
